# Array of an already defined object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object defined as

```
myObject = {
  property1 : "",
  property2 : ""
}
```

I need to create an Array of the above object.
I have tried using

```
myArray = myObject[].
```

But it doesn't seem to work.Is there any way that we can create an array of a predefined object in javascript.

Comment: What do you want to be stored in the array.

Comment: I'd maybe take a step back and check out a JS tutorial rather than trying to invent syntax--might be more efficient.

Comment: @MrGeek ... Instances of `myObject` like he said.

Comment: This is not a duplicate to that post

Comment: What result do you expect? Something like `var myArray = ["", ""]`, or `var myArray = [{property1 : "", property2 : ""}]`, or something else?

Comment: This may help. I made it awhile back when I needed to turn an object into an array.  https://jsfiddle.net/sxa6heto/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
Is there any way that we can create an array of a predefined object in javascript?
```

No, in JavaScript, you can't type the content of your array at the declaration of your array.

What you are looking for is TypeScript.

Comment: Bad news!! Thanks anyways